# hibernate, stackoverflow with particular entity mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Satellite implements Serializable, Comparable<Satellite> {
    @NotNull @Id
    private long id;
    .....
    @OrderColumn 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "satellite", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<DataModel> dataModel;
}
```

and a child entity:

```
@Entity @IdClass(value=DataModelPK.class)
public class DataModel implements Serializable, Comparable<DataModel> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3416403014857250990L;
    @Id
    private int orbit;     // related to reference orbit file
    private int dataPerOrbit;   // in Gbit
    @ManyToOne @Id
    private Satellite satellite;
}
```

originally, `DataModel` was an embeddable entity, but for a better control over the primary key and the underlying structure of the db, I switched to a more traditional model.

The point is, during the loading of the entity now it generate a stack overflow!! I think there is some cyclic loading between those two entities and it got stuck!

I'm thinking to revert everything back to what it was, but I wish to understand why it gives me this error.

Comment: This code looks fine at first glance and I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Can you post the stack trace (you can leave out the repeats)?

Comment: Can you please add the code for DataModelPk class to this post?

Answer (score 0):

You have @IdClass for DataModel specified to be DataModelPK.class but your @Id annotation is on an int field.

This is a problem, it may be causing you stackoverflow but I am not certain.

Update I now see the second @Id annotation so I stand corrected, I will investigate furtuer.

Comment: it is a composite pk (orbit, satellite). The other class is just a wrapper. I thought this is the right way of doing it but I'll investigate further.